# Google Sheets Countif with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a Google Sheet  am trying to count the occurrences of a value ("R") in a row (11) where the same column in a different row (4) has the value ("Future") ie in how many columns do I have "R" and "Future".
My current formula is
=countifs(M11:BM11,"R",M$4:BM$4,"Future")

Comment: Show few sample data or share sample workbook.

Comment: Strangely seems to work for me now with my original formula. Not sure but I think it must have been the process of finally asking for help that tipped it over!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(M11:BM11, M11:BM11="R", M4:BM4="Future")))
```